# How to finding distance between camera and detected object using openCV in python?

Tags: python, opencv, image-processing, distance

I want to find out the distance between the camera and the people (detected using the HOG descriptor) in front of camera.I'm looking into more subtle approach rather than calibrating the camera and without knowing any distances before hand.

This can fall under the scenario of an autonomous car finding the distance between the car in front.

Can someone help me out with a sample code or an explanation on how to do so

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please see [these guidelines](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) on how to create a Minimal, Complete and Verifiable code sample in your post.

Comment: You might be able to estimate distance using the average size of a human feature (size of head?) you can match against the features of the people you detect, but it's very much an estimate. AFAIK autonomous cars use ranging (i.e. Radar/lidar) to establish distance. Good luck and please report back when (if) you succeed.

Comment: @barny without sensors is the goal :( , a raspberry pi project

Answer (score -2):

I am sorry but finding a distance is a metrology problem, so you need to calibrate your camera. Calibrating is a relatively easy process which is necessary for any measurements.

Let's assume you only have one calibrated camera, if the orientation/position of this camera is fixed relatively to the ground plane, it is possible to calculate the distance between the camera and the feet of somebody (assuming the feet are visible).

Comment: I don't think it's as simple as calibrating the camera. The example you give only works because the foot is on a known plane, and cars don't have feet on the ground In the more general case of a car of unknown size at an unknown plane, this simply isn't possible. That's geometry for you.

Comment: If you do not calibrate your camera, you will never be able to any conversion between pixel and real distance.

Regarding calibration, if your camera can be approximated by the pinhole camera model + lens distortion, you can use eg. the OpenCV calibration sample codes. All you need is to take 3 or more pictures of a reference pattern. It is fully automatic, this is why I say it is easy. If your camera is more complex, eg. there is a catadioptric system, then yes the calibration is more complex. Note that no details were given about the camera.

Comment: @VincentVidal a normal pinhole camera , more specific raspberry pi camera module

Comment: Calibrating the camera does NOT in any general way establish a relationship between pixels and real distance. A pixel can represent something close or something distant - calibration does not change that.

Comment: Yes. I meant that calibration was necessary for measurements. I didn't say calibration was enough for measurements, you need more information for that, something that will intersect your ray from the camera center to your pixel. Without calibration you don't know the direction of that ray.